# Equal spacing between equations on a page

Tags: spacing, equations

I am writing a short quiz for my students in LaTeX, however I am having trouble with the spacing.  The two equations I have are:

```
 $\int sin^3(x)cos^{\frac{3}{2}}(x)dx$
 \vspace{20pc}

 $\int \frac{3x^2+2x+4}{(x-1)^2(x+1)} dx$
```

I use `\vspace{20pc}` to give a gap between both equations to give room for the students to solve it by hand.  However, I want to have an equal amount of room on an entire page for both problems.  I used `\vfill` thinking that would work but it simply puts both equations to the top of the page.  Is there a way that LaTeX will automatically generate an equal spacing for both problems on a page?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Take a look at [`mathexam`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathexam) package

Comment: @Corentin, thank you for the beginners tutorial

Comment: @leo, that's a great package, however I am using a different one that does something similar.

Comment: @Werner, That's exactly what I am after.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting a vertical fill between each item would leave an equivalent gap between the questions and to the end of the page boundary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item $\displaystyle \int \sin^3(x)\cos^{\frac{3}{2}}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$

  \vfill

  \item $\displaystyle \int \frac{3x^2+2x+4}{(x-1)^2(x+1)}\,\mathrm{d}x$

  \vfill
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```