# Latex: Equal spacing between equations on a page

Tags: equations, spacing

I am writing a short quiz for my students in latex, however I am having trouble with the spacing.  The two equations I have are:

```
 $\int sin^3(x)cos^{\frac{3}{2}}(x)dx$
 \vspace{20pc}

 $\int \frac{3x^2+2x+4}{(x-1)^2(x+1)} dx$
```

I use `\vspace{20pc}` to give a gap between both equations to give room for the students to solve it by hand.  However, I want to have an equal amount of room on an entire page for both problems.  I used `\vfill` thinking that would work but it simply puts both equations to the top of the page.  Is there a way that latex will automatically generate an equal spacing for both problems on a page?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great, I posted it there.  Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Inserting `\vfill` between the two equations, and `\vfill` after the second will leave a stretchable gap between both (sharing it 50/50).

This answer was provided by Werner found at [Tex StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102051/latex-equal-spacing-between-equations-on-a-page)